# Macbook 8.2 wifi drivers- No internet connection

Tags: wireless, drivers, macbook-pro

I have a 17inch late 2011 macbook pro and am trying to get the wifi drivers installed but I am trying to do so without an ethernet cable connected.  My only access to the internet is wireless, so I was wondering whether there is a way to manually download and install the drivers since I can't get them by doing the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would really **really** try to get a wired connection with your Macbook pro. It will be easier. It's always a good idea to have wired as a backup, in case say an update knocks out your wireless drivers or you accidently uninstall the drivers.

Okay, since you said you can't get a wired connection, this should help you install the drivers without a wired connection. You will need an install CD of Ubuntu (or perhaps a USB drive with the CD image mounted on it).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

From the webpage:

"**No Internet access**

If you do not have any other means of Internet access on your computer, you will have to install the bcmwl-kernel-source package from the restricted folder under ../pool/restricted/b/bcmwl on the Ubuntu install media.

Note: Systems installed from CDROM can simply add the install CD as a package source and install bcmwl-kernel-source, automatically installing the required dependencies."

Good luck!